# Is always two times an even semiprime at a distance $1$ or prime to the closest previous odd semiprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, semiprimes

This is an observation regarding the semiprimes, also named 2-almost primes, [biprimes](https://oeis.org/A001358), or the product of two primes. This week I do not have a computer, only a tablet (hospitalized with a lot of free time to enjoy Maths!) so I just can read and use a pen and a notebook for calculations.

> Basically it seems that two times an even semiprime ($2p$), this is $4p, p \in \Bbb P$ is located a a prime distance or distance $1$ of the previous odd semiprime of the list (except for the first element of the list, $4$, that has no odd semiprimes below $8$).

I was able to verify this for the first elements available on the OEIS list (linked above in the first paragraph) and then I took random samples from the link at OEIS to the big list of the [first $10000$ elements](https://oeis.org/A001358/b001358.txt).

> E.g. The biprime $6 \cdot 2 = 12$ and the closest previous odd semiprime is $9$ at a distance $3$.

For instance, a similar test like "the double of a non even semiprime is at a distance $1$ or prime of the closest previous odd semiprime" does not hold. There are quick counterexamples.

I would like to share the following questions:

> 1. Is there a counterexample? I can not run a computer test, if somebody could confirm if the observation is true or false in some extent that would be great.
> 2. What would be behind this kind of property (quite similar to the Fortunate numbers conjecture). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the conjecture is not true.

I wrote a (messy) Mathematica program, which told me the smallest counter example is $218$. The largest odd semiprime smaller than $218\times2$ is $427$, and $218\times2-427=9$ which is not prime.

A couple other counter examples are $466$ and $746$.

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback! When I wrote this question I was at the hospital and I left it written but did not have enough time to review it lately.

Comment: @iadvd It was a fun problem to mess with! Thanks for creating it

Comment: Agree with your findings. The odd primes $p$ such that the least $j>0$ that makes $4p-j$ an odd semiprime is composite, are `109, 233, 373, 523, 601, 683, 751, 863, 883, 1231, 1237, 1361, 1381, 1399, 1423, 1619, 1699, 1747, 1777, 1873, 2011, ...`. In the subsequence where $p$ equals `373, 523, 1423, 2953, 3067, 3137, 3539, 3583, 4049, 4513, 4877, 5113, 5381, 6529, 7057, 8831, 8999, 9041, 9791, 9811, ...` the $j$ value is not a prime power either.